# Differentiate change event incurred by user or script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've encountered a situation where some script changes a select/radio/checkbox. That fires the change event. However I need, separately, an event to tell me the user changed the element, and obviously when change fires from the script it registers as a user change.

Is there a way to prevent a script from firing the change event when you alter the value of a select/radio/checkbox?

Comment: Showing your code could help, regular script doesn't fire the change event, what are you doing there?

Comment: I'm sure if i go `$("select").val("2");` it will fire the change event

Comment: It will not fire the change event(not just because you have syntax error...)

Comment: Hmm well whatever is happening is firing the event, and I'm not triggering it myself. @benastan 's answer seems viable

Comment: it depends on the focus.

Comment: Do you trigger to change event or it just fire after you change the value with your script?

Comment: @gdoron the latter. It fires when i change the value with script

Comment: @gdoron Ah true! Okay, well I will troll through my code to try and figure out why this is happening and repost soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and pass an additional parameter when triggering the event from code.

For example:

```
$('select').bind('change', function(e, isScriptInvoked) {
    if (isScriptInvoked === true) {
        // some code for when artificial
    } else {
        // some code for when organic
    }
});

// Trigger the event.
$('select').trigger('change', [true]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function changeEvent(){
    if(this.type.toLowerCase()=='select' || this.type.toLowerCase()=='radio' || this.type.toLowerCase()=='checkbox')
        return false;
    else{
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Wont that prevent all the types mentioned from firing any change events?

Comment: I'm almost sure it doesn't answer the OP question, plz read it again.

Comment: Well he wants to prevent firing onchange event. changeEvent, which is the function called by the onchange event, checks if the type of the element that fired the event is one of select/radio/checkbox and if it does, the function returns false and doesn't execute the code

Comment: @MarkLinus you miss understand the question. I do not want to discriminate on what was changed, i want to prevent firing if it was changed in script.

Comment: no he wants to differentiate between user and script initiated events